# Firebase Database - get child without chilldren of node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database firebase]

When i use this method i obtain all nodes of modelos with posts nodes and your nodes.

Are There someway to get all nodes without nodes of children?

```
 getFirebaseDatabaseReference().child("users")
            .child(""// index do child).child("modelos").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // Return 

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to [denormalize your data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).

[De-nest your posts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) by taking it out of your modelos node, and then put each post node under a matching $id. It will look something like this:

```
- modelos
  - 1
    - active
    - created
    - etc...
  - 2
  - etc...

- posts
  - 1
    - title
    - body
  - 2
  - etc...
```

Then you'll be able to look up your post data only when you need to.